# How do I detect arrow keys pressed using curses in C?

Tags: c, input, key, ncurses, curses

In trying to get input from the arrow keys via curses (ncurses) it won't catch as KEY_UP etc.  I used the keypad function with a true argument but getch still returned an escaped sequence.  How do I shift through the values returned by getch() and grab the arrow keys specifically?

Comment: As of 2023, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75499310/6013016) is the solution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was storing `getch()` calls as char's when they were supposed to be int's. Works perfectly after the switch.

Comment: Actually, this should have been closed because the question did not show the program that would have demonstrated the problem.

Answer (score 24):

I found the same problem on Mac OS X. But it was resolved by adding the following:

```
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
```

Comment: This and storing `getch` as `int` worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 9):

Standard (VT100-like) terminals send a sequence of characters when the arrow keys are pressed. You just have to keep track of whether or not these are pressed in sequence. Here are the char's to watch for:

```
Down Arrow  0x1B 0x5B 0x42
Left Arrow  0x1B 0x5B 0x44
Right Arrow 0x1B 0x5B 0x43
Up Arrow    0x1B 0x5B 0x41
```

Comment: Are there escape codes you could enter as a key combination or sequence using ctrl for these?

Comment: No need; you can type them directly. 0x1B = esc, 0x5B = [, and 0x41 - 0x44 = A - D. Type esc[D in your terminal, and the cursor moves to the left.

Comment: This approach pretty much fully defeats the whole purpose of working with curses library in the first place :-)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question