# Arrow Keys in on OS X

Tags: c, input, console, getch

I'm trying to make a little game for the console, so I need to check which Arrow key is pressed. Can't find anything useful in the internet.

So far I tried this:

```
printf("%i", getch());
```

but getch() returns always 27, no matter what arrow I'm pressing.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curses getting arrow keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182665/curses-getting-arrow-keys)

Comment: Before asking us, you should have asked google before. Here is a fine link that I found by googeling for "c arrow-key": http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/55808/how-do-you-check-if-arrow-keys-are-pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

arrow keys are internally represented by the characters ESCAPE + "[" + a letter. depending on which arrow key it was: "A" for up, "B" for down, "C" for right, "D" for left.

and ESCAPE is #27. so what's likely happening is you're getting THREEE characters for an arrow press, not just one. you're getting 27 (escape), 91 "[", and then something in the 65-68 range ("A"-"D").