# keyboard scan codes in c linux and windows

Tags: c++, c, linux

okay so i have a program i am writing , and basically i am going to be taking input for keyboard keys such as left arrow, right arrow, up and down etc and my question is , in what is the best option to scan in these keys so that i can make my program run both in linux and windows

and what am i scanning exactly? am i supposed to scan the ascii values and store them in int? chars? or is it another way to do this ? i have searched the internet and i am finding that the kex values for keyboard scan codes are e0 4b e0 4d e0 48 e0 50

but when i actually scan the values using getchar() and store them into ints i get 4 values for each key pressed namely for example 27 91 67 10 ,  27 91 68 10

i understand that each key has press release and other values attached to it , so should i be scanning for the 67 68 etc range?

or is there another way to do this

i am writing the program using c language

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curses getting arrow keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182665/curses-getting-arrow-keys)

Comment: You are confusing scan code with char code.

Comment: It depends if you are coding a terminal application (then I would suggest using a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) or a graphical application (then use a toolkit like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) ....)

Comment: does ncurses also provide the api to create windows and apply images or videos to them?

Comment: also does SDL2 and ncurses do the same thing? because i was learning this api recently and it does have keyboard events, however i am curious to know which is better so that i can port my program over to both linux and windows

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, it seems like you're seeing [ANSI escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). They are used by text terminals, and start with the Escape character, which is `'\x1b'` (decimal 27).

This is probably not what you want, if you want to make something keyboard-controllable in direct, game-like manner you need to use "raw" input. There's plenty of references for that, look at ncurses for instance.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, that what I said, a "sequence" is generally more than one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and use the command `xev`. You can then press any key you want and see its corresponding codes. You can also move and click the mouse to see what happens there.